# What is a more efficient way to write this python code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-02-25','2022-02-26','2022-02-25'],
                   'attempt_1':[1,0,0],
                   'attempt_2':[0,0,1],
                   'attempt_3':[1,1,0]})

df1
```

The following code takes 1hr 30mins to process about 252k rows and 75 columns. Unfortunately, that is too long and I don't know if there is any method out there that can replace(?) this to reduce the processing time.

```
dategrp = set(df1["date"])
dfs_to_dategrp = []

for trial in df1.columns[:]:
    save_sf = {k:{"success":0, "fail":0} for k in dategrp}
    for c in dategrp:
        save_sf[c]["success"] += len(df1[(df1["date"]==c) & (df1[trial]==1)])
        save_sf[c]["fail"] += len(df1[(df1["date"]==c) & (df1[trial]==0)])
        new_df1 = pd.DataFrame(save_sf)
        new_df1 = new_df1.T
    dfs_to_dategrp.append(new_df1)
    
result= pd.concat(dfs_to_dategrp, axis = 1)

result
```

So in the dataframe, the columns are populated randomly with 1s (success) and 0s (fail). This code goes through each rows and columns (this method is too long) to group and total the 1s and 0s to the date of occurence.

Here is the output

[image]

Any help given will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add sample data, ideally as a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)).

Comment: You build `(df1[trial]==1)` and `(df1[trial]==0)` over and over again in the sub-loop, you should do it once for every `trial` in the first loop.

Comment: Also your `new_df1` is created at each step of your second loop but you actually only use the final result so that should go out of your second loop. You are also looping twice over the `dategrp`, once in the dict comprehesion and then again just after. In your case, you should drop the dict comprehension and build it in your main  loop. That means you would go through it only once. Finally, iterating through `df` like this is not recommended. If you share data as mentioned by @Timus, we can try to help with using `apply()` or vectorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch: If your dataframe `df1` looks somehow like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": ["2022-03-09", "2022-03-09", "2022-03-10"],
     "trial_1": [1, 0, 1], "trial_2": [1, 1, 1], "trial_3": [0, 0, 0]}
)
df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
```

```
        date  t_1  t_2  t_3
0 2022-03-09    1    1    0
1 2022-03-09    0    1    0
2 2022-03-10    1    1    0
```

then you could use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) do something like

```
def success(ser): return ser.sum()
def failure(ser): return ser.eq(0).sum()
result = df1.groupby("date").agg(**{
    **{f"{col}_success": (col, success) for col in df1.columns if col != "date"},
    **{f"{col}_failure": (col, failure) for col in df1.columns if col != "date"}
})
```

to get a `result` like

```
            t_1_success  t_2_success  t_3_success  t_1_failure  t_2_failure  \
date                                                                          
2022-03-09            1            2            0            1            0   
2022-03-10            1            1            0            0            0   

            t_3_failure  
date                     
2022-03-09            2  
2022-03-10            1
```

or

```
result = df1.groupby("date").agg(
    **dict(col
           for pair in [[(f"{c}_success", (c, success)), (f"{c}_failure", (c, failure))]
                        for c in df1.columns if c != "date"]
           for col in pair
    )
)
```

to get

```
            t_1_success  t_1_failure  t_2_success  t_2_failure  t_3_success  \
date                                                                          
2022-03-09            1            1            2            0            0   
2022-03-10            1            0            1            0            0   

            t_3_failure  
date                     
2022-03-09            2  
2022-03-10            1
```

Another option:

```
result_1 = df1.assign(length=1).groupby("date").sum()
result_2 = result_1.rsub(result_1["length"], axis=0)
result = pd.concat(
    [result_1
     .drop(columns="length")
     .rename(columns={c: f"{c}_success" for c in result_1.columns}),
     result_2
     .drop(columns="length")
     .rename(columns={c: f"{c}_failure" for c in result_2.columns})],
    axis=1
)
```